# Write a loop in Python to print out the words when the condition is valid

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I want to learn how to write a loop in Python to print out numbers of words if the following condition is valid.

```
# sys.setdefaultencoding() does not exist, here!
import sys
reload(sys)  # Reload does the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')

import tushare as ts
import pandas as pd

df = ts.get_tick_data('002428','2015-03-02')
df.head(10)

for volume in df:
   if volume = 777:
       print "buy signal"
   elif volume = 12345:
       print "wait and see"
   else:
       print "nothing"
```

[image]
It seems doesn't work. And I want all the filtered data can be stored in the pandas Dataframe format.

Comment: `It seems doesn't work` in what way?

Comment: Your for loop won't work because the iterable object that is returned are the columns and not the rows, you need to loop over the index values so `for i in df.index: #do something`

Comment: can you show the result of "print df.head()"?

Comment: @jay,I just put it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Reut mentioned, you need to use '==' instead of '=' for a comparison. Also the loop

```
for volume in df:
  do stuff
```

loops through the columns in the data frame. If you want to loop through the values in a column do it like this:

```
for i in df['volume']:
  do stuff
```

if you want to store the results in your data frame, I would define a function and then apply it to the data frame like this:

```
def my_func(volume):
    if volume == 777:
        return "buy signal"
    elif volume == 12345:
        return "wait and see"
    else:
        return "nothing"

df['type'] = df.volume.apply(my_func)
```

and the last step, if you want to filter it to only "buy signal" rows do this:

```
new_df = df[df['type'] == 'buy_signal']
```

Comment: There is an error in your function. I assume it could be 12345: , may be should '12345'?

Comment: I want to do the loop by each row values named volume.

Comment: can you give the error output? if the data is stored as text instead of an int/float, you're right it should have quotes around the numbers

Comment: I just pull out the pic. Thanks!

Comment: Now it's not the syntax problem, it is the row not the column I need to filter out all the row values that condition meets.

Comment: ah, I found the error in my function, it's not indented properly... fixing

Comment: if you want to filter the data frame do it like this:
"new_df = df[df['volume'] == 777]"

Comment: can you pull the code in your edit? It seems hard to filter by row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72095/discussion-between-jay-s-and-lu-yu).

Answer (score 2):

To compare items use the comparison operator (`==`), not the assignment operator (`=`), also as @EdChum mentioned in comments, you're iterating the columns. To iterate a column use `df[column_name]`:

```
for volume in df['volume']:
    if volume == 777:
            print "buy signal"
        elif volume == 12345:
            print "wait and see"
        else:
            print "nothing
```

Comment: yeah, i just changed but it still gives me nothing print. But I am sure there are some volumes equals to 777.

Comment: print the `volume` variable to see what is actually there.

Comment: Sorry your answer is wrong, the iterable returned from `df` are the columns not the rows as the OP is intending

Comment: @EdChum It's not *wrong*, It's partial. If you can shed light on more that's wrong that will be great. I don't know what the user is doing (I don't have his data) so I helped with what I could.

Comment: You've corrected the syntax error but iterating over a df will return columns and not rows so yes your answer is partially correct but it doesn't fully answer his question

Answer (score 1):

Use ==, not =. And you aren't looping through the df like you think you are. You're just looping through the columns and you need to loop through the rows.

```
for index in df.index:
    volume = df.loc[index,'volume']
    if volume == 777:
        print index, volume, "buy signal"
    elif volume == 12345:
        print index, volume, "wait and see"
    else:
        print index, volume, "nothing"
```